# Conditional Ternary Operator for v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, v-model

I'm trying to do the following in my `Vue` application:

```
<template v-slot:cell(selected)="{ item }" >
  <b-checkbox
      v-model="item.selected != undefined ? item.selected : defaultCheckbox"
  ></b-checkbox>
</template>
```

I have to make sure `item.selected` is not undefined or else I get an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (selected)`. When I use the conditional ternary operator in my `v-model`, I get a `Syntax Error: Unexpected token`. Why is that? How do I fix this so that I can still use `item.selected` even if it's not defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-if/else` directives to define checkboxes for both cases:

```html
<b-checkbox v-if="item.selected"
      v-model="item.selected"
  ></b-checkbox>
<b-checkbox v-else
      v-model="defaultCheckbox"
  ></b-checkbox>
```